# Latex charts similar to scientific graph

Tags: pgfplots

I found this awesome library for python which enables drawing nice plots https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots
is it possible to create similar styled graphs with latex ? I have used pgfplots but they don't look nowhere near with this style

[image: Scientific Plot]

Edit:
First of all, I am newbie to latex and pgfplots.

So far I have created a tikzpicture and received error for domain p for the function

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
            ylabel = {Current ($\mu$A)},
            xlabel = {Voltage (mV)},
            scaled ticks=false,
        ]
           \addplot[domain=0:1.4,domain p=10:20]{x ^ (2 * p + 1) / (1 + x ^ (2 * p))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

It gives an output like the following
[image]

What I am trying make is the ticks on both x and y axis, method to define colors each time I add a new plot, and making the y axis start from 0 to 1.2

Also do I need to specify samples large to make the graph look like linear rather than squares showing the values ?

Comment: The simple answer is **yes**. And besides the `cycle list` the default style isn't that far away from the image you are showing in your question. If you want to help us to replicate the exact style it would be nice if you could show us your current best result. Otherwise your question tends to sound like a "Just do it for me" question.

Comment: Hello thank you for the feedback, I have updated the post sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. A `pgfplots` graph. See the code for further explanations. My thanks to @StefanPinnow for the improvements he suggested.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,
colormap/Dark2,             %activate the colormap for the sequence of plots
legend pos=north west       % legend in NW corner of canvas
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0.75,xmax=1.25,ymin=0,ymax=1.2, % set x- and y-axis limits
  domain=0.75:1.25,                    % Calculate function values in the interval 
  samples=101,                         % Number of points to calculate for functions
  no markers,                          % no markers on plots
  smooth,                              % draw smooth functions
  tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, %tick label styling (e.g. number of decimal points)
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1},
  cycle list name=Dark2,               % colormap for functions
  x SI prefix=milli,x unit= V,         % SI units on x axis
  y SI prefix=micro,y unit= A,         % SI units on y axis
  xlabel={Voltage},                    % x axis label
  ylabel={Current}                     % y axis label
]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}          % Make a space at the top of the legend table for a heading
\addlegendentry{\hspace{-.6cm}\textbf{Order}}   % Add the legend table heading
\foreach \p in {10,15,20,30,50,100} {        % Plot the function at p=0.1, 0.12 etc
  \addplot{x ^ (2 * \p + 1) / (1 + x ^ (2 * \p))};
  \addlegendentryexpanded{\p}          % Add the function to the legend
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good attempt! Maybe some comments: Most important, please add (non-automatic) `domain=0.75:1.25` to the `axis` options, because that is the only range you **show**. But without that statement `domain` defaults to the range -5 to 5 and thus calculates a lot more. That is also why you have to use a that high `samples` number. Given the `domain` you can reduce to `samples=101` to show up the same "precision" as with your current version.

Comment: And second the `grid` and first `tick label style` keys are superfluous in this code, because you given the keys their default values.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for the feedback. That's an excellent tip on the domain. I am going to leave the tick label style because my observation is that manipulating the tick labels is not intuitive for most beginners, By leaving this code embedded in the axis options it at least gives people a starting point for what needs to be changed should they need to do that. I'll add this explanation to the post. For me, it helps with having too many code chunks to remember, especially when those details change from graph to graph.

Comment: You are welcome. My comment was just for `/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true`. I personally never had to change this. You? Then keep `domain` and `samples` keys together, because they belong together. A better explanation for these keys is then: `domain` = "Calculate function values in the interval ..."; `samples` = "Number of points to calculate for functions"

Comment: @StefanPinnow My standard practice is to make plots with `font=\sffamily` added as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment. If I don't include `tick label style = {/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}`, the tick labels are roman so this is just a carry over from my standard style. I'll delete it.